# My first C compile with gcc. Which file do I use?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

This is my first time compiling a C application. I'm using gcc on a Ubuntu box. Tutorials say to use syntax:

```
gcc main.c -o HelloWorld
```

but my program doesn't have a "main.c".

Can anyone suggest a command line for the application based on the directory listing below?

```
docs  lib  License  major.awk  Makefile  README  release.awk  src  WARNING

./docs:
ChangeLog.txt  Contributors.txt  DataTypes.txt  Makefile  New_help_needed.txt  Porting.txt  Readme.txt  undoc_file_struct.txt  undocumented_df1.txt  WARNING.txt

./lib:
attach.c        disableforces.c  echo.c          floatstuff.c  Makefile      protected_read_2.c   protected_write_3.c  resetmemory.c  typedwrite.c     wordblockwrite.c
closefile.c     downloaddone.c   enableforces.c  getedit.c     nameconv5.c   protected_read_3.c   protected_write_4.c  senddf1.c      uploaddone.c
creatememory.c  downloadreq.c    fileread.c      getstatus.c   openfile.c    protected_read_4.c   readbytesphysical.c  setpriv.c      uploadreq.c
defs.c          dropedit.c       filewrite.c     libabplc5.h   plcmodereq.c  protected_write_2.c  readsectionsize.c    typedread.c    wordblockread.c

./src:
absetmode.c  abstat.c  abtypedread.c  abtypedwrite.c  abupload.c  abwordread.c  abwordwrite.c  Makefile  Makefile.old  name.c  section.c  slcread.c  slcwrite.c  stress.c
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a Makefile in your top-level directory, just build it with

```
make
```

Comment: Thanks, Frank. The command worked. The compile had a load of errors. Time to study ...

Answer (score 1):

> my program doesn't have a "main.c".

There is no rule that the main() function should be in a file named main.c.

> Can anyone suggest a command line for the application based on the
>   directory listing below?

Since your application uses a Makefile , you must use a make utility. The Make utility will automatically invoke the compiler to build the application.

Generally just go to the topmost directory,of your application and simply open a terminal in that directory and run make.

```
$make
```

If there are no errors, your application will be built successfully. There are more make commands that can be used like `make all` and `make clean`, just have a look inside the application's Makefile to know what other make options are supported.

If you are new to Makefiles , i suggest this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31488/Makefiles-in-Linux-An-Overview).

Comment: Thanks, Barath, for the additional detail.